# Django template doesn't see data of db

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

While learning it, I faced with an issue, when I'm trying to show data from db, template doesn't see it. I tried to remove db and migrations and create new with new objects, but it didn't helped.
models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class Product(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(
        max_length= 100,
        verbose_name= 'Name'
        )
    description= models.TextField(max_length= 500)
    photo= models.ImageField(upload_to= 'photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    price= models.FloatField(validators= [MinValueValidator(2.0), MaxValueValidator(1000000.0)],)
    amount= models.IntegerField()
    last_updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category= models.ForeignKey(
        "Category",
        verbose_name= 'Category',
        default='Unselected',
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT
        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Product"
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    print(request)
    product=Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'main.html',{product :'product'})
```

template file:

```
{% for item in product %}
    <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
    {% if item.photo %}
    <img src="{{item.photo.url}}" alt="Not found">
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    <h2>{{item.price}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

I didn't show full html file,due to stackoverflow didn't let me to post it, because there is a lot of code, and no text

Comment: change` {product :'product'}` to `{'product' : product }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**change  :**

```
return render(request,'main.html',{product :'product'})
```

**to :**

```
return render(request,'main.html',{'product' : product})
```